# is padding input images better than resizing image?

Tags: machine-learning, data, transfer-learning, image-preprocessing

I am working with images and was thinking of pre-training `VGG19` and `EffecientNETB0` model on my dataset. However, a query:-

Is padding the images then using `EfficientNET` better than having dynamic shapes with `VGG19`?

My data is of a very weird shape (it's a panorama) so that's why I was confused as to whether I should use `VGG19` or `EfficientNET` because EN would require heavy padding and cropping while VGG won't.

> In short, is it more beneficial to pad images and use them, or does it yield more performance if I have a model that can accept data of any dimension?

Is there some theoretical explanation for what I should use?

Comment: Hi @neelg don't you want to keep aspect ratio of the "data" part of the image the same?  You'll not get that by resizing (i.e. stretching)??

Comment: It would be great to know what you explicit mean by 'performance' (e.g. runtime, generalisation [predictive]), before answering this question!

Comment: @shepan6 overall accuracy (predictive and generalization power) of the model